# Flash Pro CS6 SWF animation doesn't loop with Java Script

Tags: javascript, html, flash, fullscreen

I'm trying to play in Full Screen an SWF Flash file created in Flash Pro CS6. It plays fine in full screen. I'm still working on the details but the fact is that it doesn't loop and I need it to loop. On Flash the settings for the SWF was set to Loop but even inside Flash doesn't loop at all and I added to the timeline: stop(); so it will stop and loop at the end.

In Flash I imported my FLV file into the stage to load the external file instead of adding it to the time line because is a 35Mb video. The publishing settings for HTML has the loop option active and even on the code the Param value loop = true.

I'm really frustrated with this if you have any thoughts will be very appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

This is my code on HTML that will have my index page.

```
<div id="bg">
<script type="text/javascript">
var flashvars = {
  myFile: "AuroraBoreal.swf",
  myFileType: "flash",
  loadEffect: "PixelDissolve"   \\ kind of not working effect
};
var params = {
  id: "bg",
  name: "bg",
  wmode: "transparent",
  menu: "false"
};
var attributes = {
  id: "bg",
  name: "bg",
  wmode: "transparent",
  menu: "false"
};

swfobject.embedSWF("AuroraBoreal.swf", "bg", "100%", "100%",      "10.0.45.2","expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to embed it like this. See if something changes.

```
<div id="bg">
<OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" WIDTH="100%" HEIGHT="100%">
<PARAM NAME="movie" VALUE="AuroraBoreal.swf">
<PARAM NAME="quality" VALUE="high">
<PARAM name="wmode" value="transparent">
<PARAM NAME="loop" VALUE="true">
<EMBED src="AuroraBoreal.swf"  wmode="transparent" loop="true" quality="high" WIDTH="100%" HEIGHT="100%" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></EMBED></OBJECT>
</div>
```

Comment: That's the original way Flash Produced the published SFW file and it didn't worked either. So I don't know what do I need to do on Flash/HTML or Java Script to make it loop. Kind of out of ideas by now. Brain gone on vacations!